# Pytorch equivalent of Google Seedbank

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, pytorch

Does Pytorch have an equivalent of [Google Seedbank](https://research.google.com/seedbank/) ? Everything in Seedbank is (unsurprisingly) Tensorflow based, and I want to learn Pytorch.

Comment: I dont think there is. You could always refer to https://pytorch.org/tutorials/ (I agree that they are not as interactive as the seed bank). In general, it should be possible to find all these implementations in Pytorch as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can check out [Pytorch Hub](https://pytorch.org/hub/). Compared to Seedback, it has more emphasis on re-useable models (and less on tutorials), although many entries do have Colab notebooks for reference.